# Can Deno "compile" bundle a full webapp into a single file?

Tags: deno

I build a rest service in Deno (Oak) and also serve static files. However, when I run `deno compile` I would like to have those static files included into the single binary file that is ejected. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, neither Deno nor Oak have intentional support for this.

A downside of even doing this is that your binary file may become large. This isn't only an issue with distribution but may also slow loading and executing the binary.

Nevertheless, one way you can make "static" files available in a compiled binary is to encode the files as JavaScript modules (similar to [using WebAssembly in Deno](https://deno.land/manual@v1.25.2/webassembly/using_wasm)).

e.g. The following module encodes a static file, named `example.txt`, storing its file type, `txt`, and its contents, `hello world\n`. The contents are `base64` encoded (thank you [jsejcksn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438273/jsejcksn) for the suggestion). You can encode and decode the contents other ways as well or even use different encodings depending on the file type if you like.

`example.txt.ts`:

```
export default {
  type: "txt",
  data: "aGVsbG8gd29ybGQK",
};
```

You can programmatically create modules like this from static files.

e.g. `encode-as-module.ts`:

```
import { extname } from "https://deno.land/std@0.155.0/path/mod.ts";
import { encode } from "https://deno.land/std@0.155.0/encoding/base64.ts";

const [inputPath, outputPath = `${inputPath}.ts`] = Deno.args;
const type = extname(inputPath).slice(1);
const bytes = await Deno.readFile(inputPath);

const script = /* JavaScript */ `export default {
  type: "${type}",
  data: "${encode(bytes)}",
};
`;

await Deno.writeTextFile(outputPath, script);
```

Usage:

```bash
deno run --allow-read --allow-write encode-as-module.ts example.txt
```

Once you have your static files encoded as modules you can then change your Oak app from serving them using [`send()`](https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0#static-content) to serving them using [`context.response`](https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0#response) (passing the `type` and `body`). More work will need to be done here to encode a list of all the static files, etc. but I think what's already provided here illustrates the idea sufficiently.

Comment: (1) Why a stream? Modules can’t be read as streams, so the file needs to fit in memory on read anyway (actually, every file will need to fit in memory at the same time when the program is run if they are encoded into the module graph). (2) Why encode as a literal `UInt8Array`? At worst, the resulting size for each file is 300% larger than the input file (if all bytes’ code points are >= 100). Most existing modules I’ve seen encode as base64 then decode when reading (~33% size increase).

Comment: I used an `Uint8Array` because it was the first thing that came to mind.  I like `base64` idea. I went with a stream because I was originally thinking some files might be large but given the fact that all files have to fit in memory at runtime anyway (like we've both mentioned) then using a stream for the transform is overkill. I did enjoy writing a `TransformStream` as I've not used them much so it wasn't all in vain for me.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I think there's still value to the stream idea (perhaps the device used to encode has less memory than the device used to serve). However, the current encoding format is an anti-pattern. If you decide to update the question with a base64 `TransformStream<Uint8Array, string>`, then I think the [`std`](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std) library would also benefit from it (and probably a deserialization counterpart as well).

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `base64` encoding and for simplicity I dropped the stream for now. Thanks.

Comment: There's a reason why Deno's `std` library has its own [base64 encoding/decoding module](https://deno.land/std@0.155.0/encoding/base64.ts): the `window.btoa()` method will not produce correct output for all JS string (UTF-16) inputs. See the notes on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa#unicode_strings).

Comment: @jsejcksn I had no clue. Updated. Thank you for teaching me twice in one day!

Comment: A quality answer as always from you! Thanks a lot friend! I will chose a different path, as this is not practical to me, but very interesting to see your approach! I will post what I did (bundle & zip for release), although that will not be the answer to my question.

Comment: Actually I might even chose this route... Depending on how many static files I will get eventually.